# fixedOrder(true) not working?

Tags: assets

I thought that a simple `.fixedOrder(true)` would make the files order in the same way as in the CMS. Instead of that, there is no output. Where I go wrong?

```
{% set files = craft.assets.kind('pdf,word,excel').fixedOrder(true) %}
<section class="bestanden">
    <div class="col-12-md">
        <div class="documenten">
            <ul>
                {% for file in files %}
                <li>
                   <i class="fa fa-file-{{ file.kind }}-o"></i> <a href="{{ file.url }}" target="_blank">{{ file }}</a>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4):

`fixedOrder` only works with the `id` param. (If `fixedOrder` is `true` *and* `id` is set to a list of IDs, it will return the elements in the exact order that the IDs were listed.) It’s currently not possible to query elements in a fixed order based on any other params.

For your use case, the [|group](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#group) filter should work nicely:

```
{% set kinds = ['pdf', 'word', 'excel'] %}
{% set filesByKind = craft.assets.kind(kinds)|group('kind') %}

<section class="bestanden">
    <div class="col-12-md">
        <div class="documenten">
            <ul>
                {# Loop through the file kinds in the order we want #}
                {% for kind in kinds %}
                    {% for file in filesByKind[kind] %}
                        <li>
                           <i class="fa fa-file-{{ kind }}-o"></i> <a href="{{ file.url }}" target="_blank">{{ file }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```